# how can I make a custom sort order in listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

```dart
ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      children: [
                        ...carLogic.carsList.map((element) {
                          return carViewWidget(element, element.number);
                        }).toList(),
                        ...melkLogic.melksList.map((element) {
                          return melkViewWidget(element, element.number);
                        }).toList()
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: By sorting the list? Also, a single child Listview.builder holding a Listview doesn't make much sense

Comment: I have to show two different items on my page from two different APIs and this was the only way that I found to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `sort()` function to your list:

```
ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      children: [
                        ...(carLogic.carsList..sort((prevCar, nextCar) => prevCar.id.compareTo(nextCar.id))).map((element) {
                          return carViewWidget(element, element.number);
                        }).toList(),
                        ...(melkLogic.melksList..sort((prevMelk, nextMelk) => prevMelk.id.compareTo(nextMelk.id))).map((element) {
                          return melkViewWidget(element, element.number);
                        }).toList()
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

You can sort by any field in your classes, `id` here is just for example.
Also read documentration on `sort()` function

Comment: I have an error:  "The element type 'Car' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'."

Comment: Updated answer, try it

Comment: the error is gone but I still get the same sort